# onclick add inner text to table td's

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Currently I'm working on my React Tic-Tac-Toe App and I'm facing problem which I don't understand.

My file is very simple. I'm using one **state** and one function which is in **useEffect**. This function is supposed to choose whenever use **X** sign or **O** sign depending on current state value.

Everything was working just fine (X and O were switching on click) until I've added this condition to the **checkPlayer function**

```
if(e.target.innerText === ''){
  //add mark to the TD
}else{
  return;
}
```

This condition was supposed to prevent rewriting old inner text of **td** (For example when 1st player clicks on that td, X mark was added. But when 2nd player clicks that same td, it was rewriten to O mark).

But now, It's not switching between X and O and only writing X. Console is not throwing any errors and I don't get why is this happening.

Obviously, my goal is to prevent clicking on td, which already has some mark inside, so it won't be rewriten, state won't be changed and player won't be switched.

**My State and useEffect with function**

```
  const [sign,setSign] = useState(true)

  useEffect(()=>{
    function checkPlayer(e){
      if(e.target.innerText === ''){
      //1st player
      if(sign === true ){
        e.target.innerText = 'X';

        setSign(false)
      }
        
      //2nd player
      if(sign === false){
        e.target.innerText = 'O'
  
        setSign(true)
      }
      }else{
        return;
      }
    }

    //Convert HTML collection to an array, then add eventListener to every item in array
    let all = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    let tds = Array.from(all);

    tds.forEach(td => {
      td.addEventListener('click',checkPlayer)
    })
  },[sign])
```

**HTML part of App**

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you reproduce this on CodeSandbox and share the link